# Angular - How to get an element by id inside ngOnInit

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular13

I want to get the below checkbox element in ts to manipulate its value (checked = true)

```
<div class="input-wrapper" *ngFor="let i of rolesData">
    <input type="checkbox" name="{{i.role}}" id="{{i.role}}" class="selectedRole">
    <label for="{{i.role}}">{{i.role}}</label>
</div>
```

`i.role` is 'Software Developer'. Now the following code inside `ngOnInit` prints `null`.

```
console.log("element", document.getElementById('Software Developer'))
```

Please help.

Comment: try to implement this, in the ngAfterViewInit() function. And please make sure, the value of "rolesData" is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it prints `undefined` as `ngOnInit` is triggered when Angular initializes a component or directive.

For your scenario, you need `ngAfterViewInit` which this event is triggered after Angular renders the view. So that you can get the element from the view.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log('element', document.getElementById('Software Developer'));
}
```

Reference: [Responding to view changes](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#afterview)

---

**Updated**

According to your requirement that the `roleData` is fetched from Observable which is asynchronous. Meanwhile the `ngAfterViewInit` is the event that is triggered when Angular initializes the view but not when the view is completed.

Hence, to get the element from the view, it must be fulfilled with:

1. The observable is returned.
2. The HTML element is rendered.

For the implementation as the code below:

1. With `isDataFetchedSubject` `Subject`, when it is completed, indicate that the `roleData` observable is returned (`isDataFetched$`).
2. With `isViewRenderedSubject` `Subject`, when it is completed, indicate that the view is rendered. And this requires the `ngAfterViewChecked` lifecycle which is triggered when each time the view is rendered/changed (`isViewRendered$`).
3. Requires the observables mentioned in *1* and *2* must be completed.
4. With the `setTimeout` function to delay the function execution, continuously get the element from the view until the element is rendered.

```
isDataFetchedSubject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
isDataFetched$ = this.isDataFetchedSubject.asObservable();
isViewRenderedSubject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
isViewRendered$ = this.isViewRenderedSubject.asObservable();

ngOnInit() {
  this.rolesData$.subscribe((value: any[]) => {
    this.rolesData = value;

    this.isDataFetchedSubject.next(true);
    this.isDataFetchedSubject.complete();
  });

  forkJoin([this.isDataFetched$, this.isViewRendered$])
    .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$))
    .subscribe(([flag1, flag2]) => {
      console.log('Observable is completed');

      if (flag1 && flag2) {
        // Create a delay function to fetch element until it is existed
        let checkElementExist = setTimeout((isExisted: boolean) => {
          if (isExisted) clearTimeout(checkElementExist);

          console.log(
            '(2) element',
            document.getElementById('Software Developer')
          );
        });
      }
    });
}

ngAfterViewChecked() {
  this.isViewRenderedSubject.next(true);
  this.isViewRenderedSubject.complete();
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-b3db2d?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: It works when we set rolesData manually. Not working when I fetch data from db using subscribe.  getRolesFromDb()
  {
   this.userService.getAllUserRoles().subscribe({
      next: (res: any) => {
        this.rolesData = res;
      },
      error: (response: any) => {
        console.log("Error! could not load roles:", response.message);
      },
      complete: () => { }
    });
  }

Comment: As you are getting the `rolesData` from the API response, you only can get the HTML element for "Software Developer" after the observable/response is returned and the view is rendered.

Comment: Is there any way to do this? The thing I am trying to achieve is: I want checked values retained in the view (unchecked boxes should also be there) even after the page reloads or user comes again on the same component using the browser back button.

Comment: Not sure whether this is what you want. Based on my previous comment, you should have some sort of flags (Observable) to emit that the data is fetched and the view is rendered. Then you should able to get the HTML element from the view. [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-b3db2d?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to implement this in the ngAfterViewInit() only if the rolesData value was 
initialized before, else it should print only after the rolesData value initialized.

rolesData:any = [];
ngOnInit(){
   this.rolesData = [
      "Software Developer", "Software Tester", "Devops Engineer", "Backend Developer"
   ];
}
ngAfterViewInit(){
   console.log("element", document.getElementById('Software Developer'))
}
```